# using variables in rel attribute in jquery and $.get function

Tags: jquery, attributes, rel

i need a little help with this:

After loading a page i want to hide all submenus except the submenu for the loaded page. 
The information which submenue should not be closed stays in a php session…so I tried:

```
$.get("show-session.php", function(data){
    aktMenue =  data;   
    $(".dropmenue").next("ul:not([rel="+aktMenue+"])").hide();
    alert(aktMenue); 
    alert(data);
});
```

But it doesn't work - even though the alerted variable “aktMenue” and “data” is correct (both “aName”).

So i tried this:

```
$.get("show-session.php", function(data){
    aktMenue =  data;   
    aktMenue = “aName”;
    $(".dropmenue").next("ul:not([rel="+aktMenue+"])").hide();
    alert(aktMenue); 
    alert(data);
});
```

and this works … so why isn´t  `[aktMenue =  data;]` the same as `[aktMenue = “aName”;]` if `alert(data)` returns `“aName”` - and how can i use the `[aktMenue =  data;]` variable within the `rel` attribute

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 0):

Add single quotes around the attribute value : `$(".dropmenue").next("ul:not([rel='"+aktMenue+"'])").hide();`

Comment: Thanks for the answer - I've tried to ad the single quotes - unfortunately this dosn´t work neither...(it ignored the "aktMenue"-Variable and did hide all ul´s